# How to extract the Title/Chapters/Subchapters of a specific PDF

Tags: poppler

I am using meego with Qt 4.8.

I have installed all the poppler libraries.

My query is, if there is any PDF present at a particular location in my machine. How can I extract the title/Chapters/Subchapters of a chapter of that PDF using poppler.